# a question about geometric distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

In a faraway country, they have a strange culture where they favor girls over boys. Additionally, they know that boys are trouble, so they settle for one in a family. Thus, **each family give birth until their first son is born, and then they stop** (they never take the risk of having two boys – double trouble ...). As a result, families in this country are of the following types:

a. Boy

b. Girl, Boy

c. Girl, Girl, Boy

d. Girl, Girl, Girl, Boy

e. …
Are there more girls or more boys in this country? You may assume that **()=()=0.5**

Is the **answer is that it is equal number of boys and girls** because the Expected Value is 2, what means that for every boy there will be born a girl ?

Comment: Yes, also you can see for yourself that the expected number of boys in the above family structure is 1.

Comment: The expected number of boys per completed family is $1$ as the expected number of girls per completed family.  In addition the probabilities for each birth are equal for a boy or girl, independent of all other births.  But getting exactly equal numbers of boys and girls is unlikely (if there are $1$ million children, the probability of exactly $500000$ of each is under $0.0008$)

Comment: @Henry, so it is approximately equal ?

Comment: Yes - thanks to the laws of large numbers and the expected numbers of each being equal